# Java reflect getConstructor NoSuchMethodException error

Tags: java, reflection, getconstructor

I have one class called `ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage` as defined below

```
public class ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage
        extends java.lang.Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1354218639401L;

    public ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage() {
        super("ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage");
    }

    public ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage(
            java.lang.String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage(
            java.lang.String s, java.lang.Throwable ex) {
        super(s, ex);
    }

    public ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage(
            java.lang.Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

I am trying to do

```
java.lang.String exceptionClassName = (java.lang.String)faultExceptionClassNameMap.get(new org.apache.axis2.client.FaultMapKey(faultElt.getQName(),"Capture"));
                    LOGGER.debug("ExceptionClassName"+exceptionClassName);
                    java.lang.Class exceptionClass = java.lang.Class.forName(exceptionClassName);
                    java.lang.reflect.Constructor constructor = exceptionClass.getConstructor(String.class);
```

where `exceptionClass` is `ICwsTransactionProcessing_Capture_CWSInvalidOperationFaultFault_FaultMessage` from the log.

I am getting `NoSuchMethodException`. Why?

Comment: Is this an inner class by any chance?

Comment: No it is not an inner class.

Comment: Then I can't reproduce it. Works fine for me. My guess is that you're not using the class you think you are.

Comment: What was the code you used to initialize exceptionClass?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example (ideally with a much short class name) which demonstrates the example. Don't put it into comments. Put it into your *question*.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a fully qualified name to call `Class.forName()`? That absurdly large class name in your log does not seem to be fully qualified, unless you are placing your exception classes in the default package - admittedly a rather scary thought when combined with your class names...

Comment: Yes I removed the full package name to simplify the class name.I am not getting ClassNotFoundException or any error at this line. The error occures when trying to get the constructor, so I am assuming it is able to find the class.

Comment: @PraveenYadav: why don't you add a bit of code to list all constructors? Then create a couple of constructors with weird arguments and see if they appear in the list. If they do not appear, then you are not loading the right class...

Comment: Also make sure that the constructor is public, or use `Class.getDeclaredConstructor()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This was a Axis2 bug in the client stub code generated by wsdl2java .

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5420

The String class used in the generated code should have been java.lang.String but since the WSDL import was using microsoft serialized types, Axis2 had generated an inner class by name String.

The correct code generation should have used `java.lang.String` for the constructor reflection parameters.

It was a bit difficult to spot because the generated stub has 200k+ lines.

The bug is fixed in the unreleased Axis2 1.6.3 and 1.7 branches.

Thank you all for the help.